# GCP - Run>Function dynamic enviro variables from a database based on a google run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a run setup as a webhook that it triggering a function, what i was wondering is if it is possible to config the run in such a way that it sources variables from a database and then sets it as a enviro variable?

IE: have a webhook catch a request (googleRun), which then goes to the database (say postgreSQL), gets the set of keys/values and sets them as enviro variables) for the run in the function.

I have tried setting up run>function and send request to http location.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or any documentation that you follow?